# Connect to configuration page of Belair Networks 20E Using Linux Mint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a Belair Networks Wireless access point / Wifi Router and would like to reset it and connect to the config page to complete the setup and config for use with home wifi.

The manual or item pamphlet is here: http://www.falesia.pl/pdf/BelAir%2020E%20AP.pdf

The Model is Belair 20E

I am expecting to hear that this router is for use as an access point only and cannot be configured to use for home wifi access.

I have tried to connect to the routers config page by all obvious methods, 192.168.0.1, 192.168.1.1, checking default gateway and accessing that via browser etc.  Nothing seems to work.

I reset the unit via paperclip and pressing the reset button on back hoping to get a default IP to connect to..... all failed. no results

Answer (score 2):

If you log into the GUI page of your modem you should be able to view what devices are connected to it. The belair unit uses the IP address the modem gives it as its default login address. The username and password are root/admin123. I have this unit and it works great as home wife access point. And to do a full reset you need to hold the reset button for at least 60 seconds. This will produce a non secured wifi name belair 2.4   Another thing to note I have only been able to get into the GUI page while connected wireless to the unit. Ethernet seems to be disabled for editing

Comment: I would like to add that the GUI page is extremely loaded with options and very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [info supplied by the manufacturer](http://www.ericsson.com/res/site_JP/press/2012/doc/cg_wifi120927_eg.pdf) (Ericsson) it would appear that is a carrier-grade AP (not intended for home or enterprise use) designed for use with a central controller (the WIC8000).

So all of the configuration and control would be done at the WIC8000 controller, not on the APs themselves. That's why you probably can't figure out a way to get into the AP (because there isn't one).

Answer (score 0):

Para entrar en la configuración debes ingresar a la configuración del adaptador de red en Panel de Control - Centro de Redes y Recursos Compartidos - Luego en el panel derecho clic en Cambiar Configuración del Adaptador - Por ultimo en el adaptador de red lan hacer clic en propiedades en la ventana que te aparece doble clic en Protocolo de Internet version 4 (TCP/IP v4).

En la ventana que te sale le das al radio buton que dice "usar la siguiente direccion ip"

Donde dice Direccion IP colocas: 10.1.1.11
Donde dice Máscarad e SubRed colocas: 255.255.255.0

Aceptas todo y luego tratas de conectarte por el navegador web a la http://10.1.1.10 (Importante hay que escribir http:// la dirección sola no funcionará) y deberías poder entrar.

Nota tienes que acceder a la configuracion sin haber conectado el cable de interner ether despues que lo configures vuelve a manual entrar en la configuración debes ingresar a la configuración del adaptador de red en Panel de Control - Centro de Redes y Recursos Compartidos - Luego en el panel derecho clic en Cambiar Configuración del Adaptador - Por ultimo en el adaptador de red lan hacer clic en propiedades en la ventana que te aparece doble clic en Protocolo de Internet version 4 (TCP/IP v4). y le das optener direccion ip automaticamente despues conectas el cable de interner al belair y listo pero tiene un pequeño detalle que va a botar las direcciones ip del mismo aba en este caso porque soy de venezuela y me da maximo 2 a 5 direcciones ip porque la configuracion va acer access poin wifi si lo quieres solo wifi el va a tomar la direccion y la rebotara con su clave que tu le pongas

**English translation from Translate This addon:**

To enter the settings you must enter the configuration of the network adapter in Control Panel - Center Network and Sharing - After the panel right click Change Adapter Configuration - Finally in the network adapter lan click properties in the window that appears you double-click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP / IP v4).

In the window that comes out will you give to the radius buton that says "Use the following IP address"

Place it where it says IP Address: 10.1.1.11 Where you place says Masquerade and subnet: 255.255.255.0

Accept everything and then try to connect through the web browser to the http://10.1.1.10 (Note you must write http: // address alone will not work) and should be able to enter.

Note you have to access the settings without connecting cable interner ether after re-configure it manually enter setup must enter the network adapter settings in Control Panel - Network and Sharing Center Resources - Then in the right panel click Change Adapter Settings - Finally in the network adapter properties lan clicking in the window that appears you double-click Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP / IP v4). and give optener ip address automatically after you connect the cable interner the belair and ready but has a small detail that will throw the ip of the same address aba here because I'm from Venezuela and gives me maximum 2-5 IP addresses because the acer settings will poin wifi access if you want the wifi only going to take direction and bounce your key you put your

Comment: This automated translation obviously falls short.  Can anyone clean it up?

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset Belair20E Networks Wireless access point.
2. Assign following to your local network card: IP `10.1.1.11`, mask `255.255.255.0`.
3. Connect the cable to the Balair20E using any LAN port.
4. Open a browser and type `10.1.1.10`.

The username and password are `root` / `admin123`.

Good luck.